# How can I fix `TypeError: document.body` is null after upgrading to react bootstrap 1.0.0-beta5

Tags: react-bootstrap

I upgraded react-bootstrap

```
   "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.2",
   "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
```

,
and now I see this warning: `TypeError: document.body is null` (it seems to come from `./node_modules/react-overlays/Modal.js`)

Comment: It does seem to be related to Modal.  `import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'` causes the `document.body is null` error without even using Modal otherwise.  I believe this is related to https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays/issues/283

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be related to https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays/issues/283.  Moving the script tag from `<header>` to the `<body>` fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar.  One solution I found was to change imports from something like `import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';` to `import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';`.  I am not sure why this fixes it though.